# Entity Framework Core - Error with negative ID's at entity insertion

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When I insert a join entity to represent a many-to-many relation with Entity Framework Core 2.0.1, it shows the following error:

"*The instance of entity type 'ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value 'IdReferenciaConstructor:-2147482610, IdReferenciaFabricante:-2147482625' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.*".

It happened to me previously with the ID's being 0 (not negative) and I solved it changing the classes' schema:
[Entity Framework Core - Error inserting many-to-many relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264253/entity-framework-core-error-inserting-many-to-many-relation)

With the correct schemas, may it be a problem with the circular references? The join table, with the temporary ID's generated, references two entities which, at the same time, have a reference to the join entity.

Classes:

```
[Table("ReferenciasFabricante", Schema = "public")]
public class ReferenciaFabricante
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    //JOIN TABLE
    [InverseProperty("ReferenciaFabricante")]
    public IList<ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor> ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor { get; set; }

}


[Table("ReferenciasConstructor", Schema = "public")]
public class ReferenciaConstructor
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    //JOIN TABLE
    [InverseProperty("ReferenciaConstructor")]
    public IList<ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor> ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor { get; set; }

}


//JOIN TABLE
[Table("ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor", Schema = "public")]
public class ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor {

    [Key]
    public int IdReferenciaFabricante { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdReferenciaFabricante")]
    public ReferenciaFabricante ReferenciaFabricante { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int IdReferenciaConstructor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdReferenciaConstructor")]
    public ReferenciaConstructor ReferenciaConstructor { get; set; }
}
```

Model:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

    modelBuilder.Entity<ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor>().HasKey(v => new { v.IdReferenciaFabricante, v.IdReferenciaConstructor });
}
```

Code:

```
foreach (ApplicationCore.Entities.ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor referenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor in referenciaConstructor.ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor) {

    //ERROR
    _dbContext.ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor.Add(referenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor);
}
```

Comment: Where is `referenciaConstructor` variable coming from? Is it already attached/added to the context? If yes, then `referenciaConstructor.ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor` collection has already been processed (items are attached or added). The order of operations matters. Show the full code of the usage scenario.

Comment: @IvanStoev referenciaConstructor is not added to the context yet. None of those entities actually.

Comment: In order to help, we need a repro ([mcve]).