# Entity Framework Core 6.0.13 - Negative Foreign Key Values Inserted For Join Entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I'm encountering an issue inserting records with where a [join entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration) connects them. I am using EF Core 6.0 in a database-first situation. I have two tables, `Product` and `Rule` and a many-many relationship exists between them and is tracked by the `Product_Rule` table. When I insert a set of `Product` records with child `Rule` records through an API call, the records are inserted to the two primary tables correctly but the `Product_Rule` table just has negative values [image: example] for the foreign key values. The problem specifically occurs when inserting multiple `Product`s with child `Rule`s at the same time. A single `Product` insert works fine. My entities:

Product:

```
public class Product
{
    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

    public DateTime InsertedOn { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Rule>? Rules { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ProductRule>? ProductRules { get; set; }
}
```

Rule:

```
public class Rule
{
    public long RuleId { get; set; }

    public string RuleDescription { get; set; }

    public DateTime InsertedOn { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Product>? Products { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ProductRule>? ProductRules { get; set; }
}
```

ProductRule:

```
public class ProductRule
{
    public long ProductRuleId { get; set; }

    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    public long RuleId { get; set; }
    
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    
    public Rule Rule { get; set; }
}
```

My Configurations, using the many-many documentation I found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration):

Product:

```
public class ProductConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> entityTypeBuilder)
    {
        // Tables / Keys
        entityTypeBuilder.ToTable("Product");
        entityTypeBuilder.HasKey(product => product.ProductId);

        // Relationships
        entityTypeBuilder
            .HasMany(product => product.Rules)
            .WithMany(rule => rule.Products)
            .UsingEntity<ProductRule>(
                join => join
                    .HasOne(productRule => productRule.Rule)
                    .WithMany(rule => rule.ProductRules)
                    .HasForeignKey(productRule => productRule.RuleId),
                join => join
                    .HasOne(productRule => productRule.Product)
                    .WithMany(product => product.ProductRules)
                    .HasForeignKey(productRule => productRule.ProductId),
                join =>
                {
                    join.ToTable("Product_Rule");
                });

        // Properties
        entityTypeBuilder
            .Property(product => product.InsertedOn)
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
    }
}
```

Rule:

```
public class RuleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Rule>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Rule> entityTypeBuilder)
    {
        // Tables / Keys
        entityTypeBuilder.ToTable("Rule");
        entityTypeBuilder.HasKey(rule => rule.RuleId);

        // Relationships
        entityTypeBuilder
            .HasMany(rule => rule.Products)
            .WithMany(product => product.Rules)
            .UsingEntity<ProductRule>(
                join => join
                    .HasOne(productRule => productRule.Product)
                    .WithMany(product => product.ProductRules)
                    .HasForeignKey(productRule => productRule.ProductId),
                join => join
                    .HasOne(productRule => productRule.Rule)
                    .WithMany(rule => rule.ProductRules)
                    .HasForeignKey(productRule => productRule.RuleId),
                join =>
                {
                    join.ToTable("Product_Rule");
                });

        // Properties
        entityTypeBuilder
            .Property(rule => rule.InsertedOn)
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
    }
}
```

ProductRule:

```
public class ProductRuleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ProductRule>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ProductRule> entityTypeBuilder)
    {
        // Tables / Keys
        entityTypeBuilder.ToTable("Product_Rule");
        entityTypeBuilder.HasKey(product => product.ProductRuleId);

        // Relationships
        entityTypeBuilder
            .HasOne(productRule => productRule.Rule)
            .WithMany(rule => rule.ProductRules)
            .HasForeignKey(productRule => productRule.RuleId);
        entityTypeBuilder
            .HasOne(productRule => productRule.Product)
            .WithMany(rule => rule.ProductRules)
            .HasForeignKey(productRule => productRule.ProductId);

        // Properties
    }
}
```

My DBContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    
    public DbSet<Rule> Rules { get; set; }
    
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        // Calls base constructor only
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(MyDbContext).Assembly);
    }
}
```

My service method:

```
public async Task<bool> SaveNewProducts(IEnumerable<Product> products)
    {
        try
        {
            await _myDbContext.Products.AddRangeAsync(products);
            await _myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I looked at other SO posts including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298037/entity-framework-core-error-with-negative-ids-at-entity-insertion), but they either did not seem to match my situation or lacked a minimum reproducible example so they were of no help. I do have this entire solution [on GitHub for reference](https://github.com/tparikka/EFCoreDemo). I'm sure I am just misunderstanding something about the use of many-many relationships when an explicit join entity is defined but I can't find what from the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug when adding multiple entities in a single SaveChanges (whether batching is on or not).  To work around change your product service to insert them one-by-one in a transaction, eg

```
public async Task SaveNewProducts(IEnumerable<Product> products)
{
    try
    {
        using var tran = await _myDbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
        foreach (var product in products) 
        {
            _myDbContext.Products.Add(product);
            _myDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        tran.Commit();

        return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Here's a simplified repro:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Common;

using var db = new Db();

db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
db.Database.EnsureCreated();

var products = new List<Product>();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    var p = new Product() { ProductDescription = $"Test{i}" };
    var r = new Rule() { RuleDescription = $"Test{i}" };

    p.Rules.Add(r);
    products.Add(p);
}

db.AddRange(products);
db.SaveChanges();

Console.WriteLine("Finished");


class Db : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=EfCore7Test;TrustServerCertificate=true;Integrated Security=true",
            o =>
            {
                o.UseRelationalNulls().MaxBatchSize(1);
            })
            .LogTo(m => Console.WriteLine(m), LogLevel.Trace);
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                    .HasMany(product => product.Rules)
                    .WithMany(rule => rule.Products)
                    .UsingEntity<ProductRule>(
                        join => join
                            .HasOne(productRule => productRule.Rule)
                            .WithMany()
                            .HasForeignKey(productRule => productRule.RuleId),
                        join => join
                            .HasOne(productRule => productRule.Product)
                            .WithMany()
                            .HasForeignKey(productRule => productRule.ProductId),
                        join =>
                        {
                            join.ToTable("Product_Rule");
                            join.HasKey(e => e.ProductRuleId);
                        });


    }


}
public class Rule
{
    public long RuleId { get; set; }

    public string RuleDescription { get; set; }

    public DateTime InsertedOn { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product>? Products { get; set; } = new HashSet<Product>();


}

public class Product
{
    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

    public DateTime InsertedOn { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Rule>? Rules { get; set; } = new HashSet<Rule>();


}

public class ProductRule
{
    public long ProductRuleId { get; set; }

    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    public long RuleId { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public Rule Rule { get; set; }
}
```

Which fails after attempting to run this

```
  Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@p2='-9223372036854774807', @p3='-9223372036854774807'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO [Product_Rule] ([ProductId], [RuleId])
  OUTPUT INSERTED.[ProductRuleId]
  VALUES (@p2, @p3);
```

And which should be submitted as an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues

Comment: David, thank you for the reply! Your answer got me to do some more testing and produced an interesting bit of new information. The problem I'm experiencing only occurs if I am submitting more than one product at the same time. Can you try this out?

Comment: Thank you for the help, and taking the time to throw together a simplified reproducible example! I'll put that into a fresh repo for the EF Core team and log an issue :) I appreciate your time!